# Override max page width when viewing websites in Opera

Tags: browser, opera

I would like to specify a fixed/maximal page width for some pages I frequently visit with Opera. Or maybe just an option I can activate that limits the maximum width for a certain tab.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/) is a good example of this as it always fits the content of entries to the browser size. That means that on my 1900x1200 wide screen monitor I get line-lengths of some hundred characters. Very annoying to read.

Obviously I could just switch Opera to not be maximized, or even make a single tab only take maybe half the screen size. However I would have to do that 100 times a day. I am looking for an easier way to achieve this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I never maximise the browser window when I am using a high resolution screen like that, but if you want to do that, while not having fluid formatted sites from expanding like that, you could use user javascript scripts to control it.

I do not use Opera very much, but [it seems to have support for this natively](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/).  It looks like you can even use [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) scripts, so you will be able to find many different scripts already made by other users, for the popular sites that you use.

Comment: Hmm, it feels like a lot of effort just to configure the width of a browser page...